# Find value in Column B and copy value to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. Each sheet always has a value in column B called "General Conditions" and the value in Column C is a dollar amount. I'm trying to find the "General Conditions" value and then copy the value in Col C to a new sheet. The values are always in Col B and C, but different row numbers.

Example:
General Conditions | 658.25

This is what I sort of had working. I would ideally want to loop through all the sheets in the workbook.

```
Sub macro()

For Each c In Range(Range("B1"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If c Like "*General Conditions*" Then
    c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use loop `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: for some reason i can get the above code to work.  i swear it was working last night.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
Sub macro()
```

Dim irows As Integer

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

```
If ws.Range("B2").Value = "" Then
    irows = 1
Else
    irows = ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
End If

For Each c In ws.Range("B1:B" & irows)
    If c.Value Like "*General Conditions*" And ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow
    End If
Next c
```

Next ws

End Sub

Comment: I get Run-time error 1004 - Application defined or object defined error :(

Comment: No there isn't a value in B1

Comment: I have updated the code to allow this. Excuse the formatting - not sure what happened....

Comment: Ok not throwing an error now, but it's not copying the value to sheet 1.

Comment: You need to send what error you are getting as hard for me to tell why. Its working on my example.

Try putting a breakpoint on  
c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).EntireRow 

to see if it gets hit

Comment: How can I send you an example of what I am working with?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub macro()
    Dim c As Range

    Set c = Range("B1", Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)).Find(what:="General Conditions", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't copying the row over to "sheet1"

Comment: what do you mean? the statement `c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` copies over to "Sheet1" sheet. So what's the actual issue?

Comment: can i send you a sample file?

Comment: I don't get you: it should be you having a sample file! add some shot of your data links in your question